# Django app that checks the disk space

Tags: django

Currently, I'm working on a Django app that will check the disk space (server space in the future) and provide the user about how much space is occupied and how much is left. What is the logic behind creating this app?

In the future, I will use this logic to check the server space and display the information to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library to get the current system usage like so. Then just render it using some Django template. To get the memory use:

```
import psutil
psutil.virtual_memory()
# returns svmem(total=10367352832, available=6472179712, percent=37.6, used=8186245120, free=2181107712, active=4748992512, inactive=2758115328, buffers=790724608, cached=3500347392, shared=787554304)
```